# Most Efficient Way to Export Oracle query results to CSV in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I currently have a process that reads in up to 150,000+ records from an Oracle query and exports them to a bar-delimited CSV. The process runs each day and the record count increases with every run.

The code that I have deployed right now in production takes about 40+ minutes to run. The most time is spent loading the OracleDataReader into a DataTable. From there, the DataTable is looped through and each field is added to a StringBuilder with the delimiter and the lines are written to a file using StreamWriter.

It works and serves its purpose, but it takes ENTIRELY too long to run.

I've played around with it a bit and searched all over the place for the best method to do this, but I can't find anything that runs any faster as of yet. The most promising alternative I tried was looping through the DataReader and leaving the DataTable out of it, but that took about 30% longer.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what is the final file size?

Comment: also, there's a lot of variables here.. you need to narrow down where your performance hit is.  Is it your query?  How long does it take the query to run?  How long does it take to loop the records and construct the stringbuilder?  how long to write the file?

Comment: The query takes about 20 seconds to run. The performance hit occurs when I call datatable.load(datareader). Everything else is very quick.

Comment: You might want to look into some native Oracle methods, such as UTL_FILE, for doing this rather than trying to use .NET.

Comment: @jfrankcarr I will look into that. Wasn't aware this was possible through Oracle, so that's worth a shot.

Comment: @Dan-o Forgot to mention, final file size is ~25MB and grows by 1MB about every week or so. The DataTable.Load(DataReader) call takes anywhere between 30 minutes to an hour, currently.

Comment: @jfrankcarr Thanks for the suggestion, but it looks like that solution isn't possible in my situation.

Comment: Are you pulling the data over a dial-up connection?  ~25MB should take a few minutes - tops - to transfer.  You could try measuring the throughput between your oracle server and your client box.

Comment: @Dan-o Haha this process certainly makes it feel like dial-up with how slow it goes. I've got lots of other processes that have no speed issues from Oracle to client, but this one just hangs severely. I just can't understand how the query can run as fast as it does but writing those results to a file is like molasses. I was hoping for some sort of different approach code-wise, but I am yet to find one that goes any faster.

Comment: Well its not the file write that is your bottleneck, its data transfer from the oracle db to your client machine ( thats what `DataTable.Load(DataReader)` does ).   How are you measuring query speed?

Comment: @Dan-o Yeah I know, but that's the end I'm trying to reach and no matter what method I choose it's just super slow. I've run the query through Navicat and through my VB.NET code and received speed numbers that way.